# How to transfer data from local database to service-based database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I'm fairly new to the .NET language although I've used VBA a lot. Anyway, I was trying to make the following SQL command work properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated...

```
"INSERT INTO RepSecurity (UserID,Creds) " _
 & "SELECT Reps.UserID, InitUsers.Pwd " _
 & "FROM Reps INNER JOIN InitUsers " _
 & "ON Reps.RepID = InitUsers.RepID"
```

Some parts were left out. Plus the REPS table is a Service-Based table (`.mdf`) and the INITUSERS table is a local table (`.sdf`)

By the way, I'm coding in Visual Studio 2012 using the vb.NET language.

Comment: Just as a note = `.mdf` is a **SQL Server** (server-based) data file, `.sdf` is a **SQL Server Compact Edition** (file-based) database file

Comment: Right, I understand that much, but how do I transfer data between the two. Is it possible? My SQL statement worked perfectly in MS Access VBA.